# Show that the usual Euclidean metric and another metric $d$ are equivalent on $X = (0,\infty)\cap{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

On the set $X = (0,\infty)\cap{Q}$, given the metric $d(x,y)=|1/x-1/y|$, I want to prove that the metric $d$ and the usual Euclidean metric on $X$ are equivalent. Equivalence of metrics is defined as:

> Two metrics are equivalent if and only if they have the same convergent sequences with the same limits.

I showed that Euclidean convergence implies  $d$-convergence, but could not show the converse part. Instead, I proved that it is sufficient to show:

> For any $A\subseteq{X}$, if A is open in $(X,|.|)$, then it is open in $(X,d)$.

Currently, I am trying to show the last statement. I assumed that A is open in $(X,|.|)$, so given $a \in{A}$ $\exists r\gt0$ such that $B_{|.|} (a,r) \subseteq{A}$. Then I need to find an $s\gt{0}$ such that $B_{d} (a,s) \subseteq{A}$. Instead, I can try to prove the following:

- Pick $s\gt{0}$ so that $\forall{x}\in{X}$ whenever $d(a,x)=\frac{|a-x|}{|ax|}<s$
  , we have $|a-x|<r$

Is it possible to find such an $s\gt{0}$? I could not find a way.

Comment: (1). You showed that if $|x_n-y|$ converges to $0$ and $ y>0$ then  $|1/x_n-1/y|\to 0....$ (2). So if $|1/x_n-1/y|\to 0$ and $1/y>0$, let $x'_n=1/x_n$ and $y'=1/y.$ You have $|x'_n-y'|\to 0$ and  $y'>0$ so by (1)) you have $|1/x'_n-1/y'|\to 0.$ But $|1/x'_n-1/y'|= |x_n-y|.$

Comment: I see I missed a really basic argument. But still I wonder, is it possible to find such an $s\gt{0}$ as in my last sentence?

Comment: Let $s=t/a$ where $t\in (0,1)$ and $at/(1-t)<r .$